# making connection to database with PDO inside class

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two files file1.php and database.php. I have a class 'Connection' in database.php file. I am calling this function as passing query to class 'bar'. But I am getting two errors:

```
1.Notice: Undefined variable: conn... on line 22
2.Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in.. on line 22
```

These are the codes I am using. Thank you.

file1.php

```
require_once('database.php');
$c = new Connection();
$c->bar("Select id, firstname, lastname from users");
$c->execute();

database.php 

class Connection{
    public $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "testing_pdo";
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function bar($sql)
    {
        $this->conn->prepare($sql);
        return $this->conn->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is `$this->conn` everywhere is a class.

Comment: Inside __construct i used $conn; inside bar function i am using $this->$conn

Comment: I repeat: It is `$this->conn` everywhere is a class.

Comment: i am getting the same error

Comment: Obligatory link: [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @u_mulder he's blundered *twice* here :)

Comment: @u_mulder yes updated

Comment: @nas you should use **ONLY** `$this->conn` **EVERYWHERE** and **NOTHING ELSE**. Do you copy? Looks like not.

Comment: Please __make sure__ you understand difference between `$this->conn` and `$this->$conn`

Comment: I got it and its embarrassing too but still i am not getting the result :(

Comment: Once you've changed your class, it's time to change `file1.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made it out. I made few changes in both files.

```
database.php

class Connection{
    private $servername = "localhost";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    private $dbname = "testing_pdo";

    private $conn;
    private $error;
    private $stmt;


    public function __construct()
    {
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->error = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    public function bar($sql)
    {
        $this->stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    }

    public function resultset(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
}

file1.php

include ('database.php');
$c = new Connection();
$c->bar("Select id, firstname, lastname from users");
$c->resultset();
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I am learning about PDO. If you have better solution you can help me learn.

Comment: What's the idea with writing your own limited surrogate around PDO? While PDO is already a class, written by someone who apparently had more knowledge than you have? What's wrong with PDO that makes it impossible for you to use it as is?